# How do I style a image to a max-height based on it's orientation?

Tags: javascript, css

How do I style an image based on it's orientation ?
I have a list of  elements on a grid layout. Until now I used only lanscape images, but now I want to start using portrait images.

Is there a way to make css recognize if the height of an image is greater than the width and set height accordingly ?

I mean I can set max-height to a fixed length but the image would be distorted. What I really want is that the landscape image to mantain it's size and the portrait image to get it's height reduced to the size of landscape's height.

Is there a way of doing that ?

I was intending in using only css. But this is and Angular project, so I can use js if there isn't any other way.

To be more clear I want that these images where I used `max-width: 100%; max-height: 10em;` setting:

[image: Images with wrong size]

look like this:

[image: Images sized as I want]

So, the reduced image should be able to apear anywhere in the grid, it's not that there's an area of reduced images and a row of normal images. They can mix in the same row as shown.

Comment: `object-fit` on the image and place it within a container while the container gets the size from the grid the image can `contain`.

Comment: Just perfect. I searched for that like 2 hours before asking. Don't you want to create an answer so I can accept it ?